# Android Pie - Toast messages overwriting previous one

Tags: toast, android-toast, android-9.0-pie

Up until `Android Pie`, when I sent multiple `Toast` messages sequentially, they were all displayed sequentially. On my `API 28` emulator, when I send multiple `Toasts` at the same time, only the last one is shown. 
Is this a behavior change across `Android P`?